# Android Material ListView selected item color change

Tags: android, material-design, material-components-android

My flutter app calls native select list from webview and I need to change color of the selected item (blue radio circle/dot) to green. I already use following code to change datepicker color and this works:

```
<style name="CustomDatePickerDialogTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/custom_green</item>
</style>
```

However the list select stays blue. How can I pls change color of the selected list item too?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to replace `android:colorAccent` by `android:colorControlActivated` and `android:Theme.Material.Light.Dialog` by `android:Theme.DeviceDefault.Light.Dialog`:

```xml
<style name="CustomDatePickerDialogTheme" parent="android:Theme.DeviceDefault.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="android:colorControlActivated">@color/custom_green</item>
</style>
```

Comment: thx for your reply, unfortunately did not work :/ I suspect ...Light.Dialog or Theme.Material might not be the right place but I have no idea how does it work or how to debug/target it

Comment: Indeed is hard to debug... Did you try to replace `Theme.Material` by `Theme.MaterialComponents`?

Comment: yes, with no luck so far. I will keep trying different combinations. Thx at least for showing me the`colorControlActivated` option

Comment: you were basically right. Missing part on my side in AppTheme was calling custom theme as alertDialogTheme like this `<item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/CustomDialogTheme</item>` and I also changed parent to `android:Theme.DeviceDefault.Light.Dialog`. If you update your answer with this solution, I will mark it as correct solution :) thanks

Comment: I'm glad it works for you, I just updated the answer